# Quais as diferenças entre HTTP 1.1 vs HTTP 1.0?

Tags: http, post, get

Quais as diferenças entre eles, e para qual caso cada um é mais recomendado?

Temos a documentação do [HTTP 1.1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) e a do [HTTP 1.0](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt), mas são longas, e gostaria de uma breve explicação em português.

No caso, temos duas situações importantes, `POST` e `GET`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

HTTP 1.1 passou a exigir um *Host Header*. Antes era opcional. Com isso ficou fácil rotear a requisição entre servidores mais facilmente e até compartilhar a mesma estrutura para vários sites (*virtual hosting*).

Ele passou a permitir extensões do padrão para atender demandas específicas.

Ele passou a ter conexões persistentes (*Keep-Alive*) e *pipelining* (várias requisições na mesma conexão ocorrendo em paralelo), fundamental para dar melhor performance e facilitar a comunicação entre cliente e servidor. Para isso um *header* de conexão foi necessário.

O método OPTIONS foi introduzido.

Também adicionaram o código de estado 100 onde o servidor informa o cliente que pode enviar o que ele pretendia. Para isso o cliente manda uma prévia da requisição informando o que ele enviará se autorizado, só para citar um exemplo. Foram vários códigos novos (206, 300, 409, 410, etc.).

Também melhorou muito o suporte para cache que agora pode manipulá-lo de forma menos ingênua.

Melhorou o suporte para compressão.

Foi adicionado *digest authentication* para melhorar a segurança. Autenticação de *proxy* também passou ser possível.

Alguns recursos foram colocados para melhorar a confiabilidade.

Passou a ter suporte apropriado para lidar com línguas diferentes.

Os dados puderam ser enviados em partes evitando grandes perdas na ocasião de falhas, além do cliente poder começar renderizar antes de chegar tudo. Passou a existir a possibilidade do cliente pedir apenas uma parte do dado.

Muita coisa que já estava sendo usada no 1.0 foi formalizada no protocolo 1.1.

Que eu saiba não mudou nada no `GET` e `POST` a não ser que eles e ou demais verbos devem indicar que a requisição será feita pelo HTTP 1.1.

Se quiser uma lista mais completa da mudança veja a [RFC (seção 19.6.1)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Há um [documento com mais detalhes](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html).

O principal foi baseado [nessa pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247026/221800).

Na verdade já deveria ir para o [HTTP 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2). [FAQ](https://http2.github.io/faq/). E [pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167014/101).

E a principal mudança do [HTTP 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/3) é o uso do protocolo QUIC para transporte no lugar do TCP, permitindo mais velocidade e confiabilidade, além de permitir de manter conexão mesmo com a troca de IP.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 18):

1. Método `OPTIONS` - O método HTTP `OPTIONS` foi introduzido no HTTP 1.1, e permite obter-se metadados acerca de um recurso (URL), inclusive quais são os métodos permitidos nele.
2. O cabeçalho `Host` - Este cabeçalho é obrigatório no HTTP 1.1, mas não no HTTP 1.0. Se uma requisição for enviada sem esse cabeçalho no HTTP 1.1, o servidor deve responder com um status `400 - Bad Request`. O motivo por trás dessa mudança foi para facilitar questões referentes a roteamento e a hospedagem de páginas/sites.
3. Cache - O HTTP 1.0 tinha um suporte bem simples e primitivo de cache por meio do cabeçalho `If-Modified-Since`. Já o HTTP 1.1 tem um suporte bem melhor com os cabeçalhos `ETag`, `If-Unmodified-Since`, `If-Match`, `If-None-Match`, `Cache-Control` e `Expires`. No HTTP 1.1 também há conceitos de cache em proxies (definidos no cabeçalho `Cache-Control`).
4. Mensagem de status `100 - Continue`, que é útil para dividir uma requisição em duas ou mais partes. Serve para evitar o caso de fazer o upload de um recurso bem pesado só para ter um 404 depois.
5. Mensagem de status `101 - Switching Protocols` e cabeçalho `Upgrade`, para alternar entre HTTP e HTTPS.
6. Reúso de conexões - O HTTP 1.0 estabelecia uma conexão para cada recurso baixado em uma página (ou seja, uma conexão para o HTML, uma para cada javascript, uma para cada CSS, uma para cada figura, etc). Isso era a maior ineficiência do HTTP 1.0 e a maior motivação para a criação do HTTP 1.1. No HTTP 1.1, existe o reúso de conexões, que é provida com o cabeçalho `Connection` e os valores `keep-alive` ou `close`.
7. Melhor controle sobre o tipo da resposta que o cliente deseja, incluindo o conceito de *byte-serving* (que corresponde a requisitar apenas parte do conteúdo do recurso, possibilitando downloads paralelizados e/ou parciais) e de *content negotiation* (possibilitando ao cliente escolher qual formato melhor se adéqua as suas necessidades, caso o servidor possa disponibilizar um mesmo recurso em diversos formatos diferentes). Isso inclui os cabeçalhos `Content-Encoding`, `Content-Location`, `Content-Length`, `Content-Range` e `Content-Type`.
8. Autenticação dos tipos digest e via proxy.
9. Outros cabeçalhos específicos e códigos de status novos (203 a 206, 300, 303, 305, 406 a 415, 504 e 505).
10. Deve haver mais alguns detalhes aí.

Fontes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/247026/540552
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068
- http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.19.6.1