# Quais são as diferenças entre HTTP 2 e HTTP 1.1?

Tags: http

Foi feita uma pergunta bastante pertinente anteriormente para saber quais são as [diferenças entre o `HTTP 1.1`e o `HTTP 1.0`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153512).

Eu queria saber exatamente o mesmo mas entre `HTTP 2.0` e `HTTP 1.1`.

Adicionalmente, podem referir se o protocolo já é completamente suportado pelos *browsers* principais?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Compressão automática

No HTTP 1.1 habilitamos o GZIP para comprimir as informações que mandamos em nossas respostas. Uma boa prática que precisa ser habilitada explicitamente. No HTTP 2 GZIP é padrão e obrigatório.

### Somente os headers que mudam são re-enviados

No HTTP 1.1 os headers são enviados em **plain text, em cada requisição** (o famoso `User-Agent` por exemplo). No HTTP 2 os headers são binários e comprimidos, diminuindo o volume de dados. Além disso, é possível reaproveitar os headers para as requisições seguintes. Dessa forma, só temos que mandar os cabeçalhos que mudam. Isso reduz as requisições e as deixa menos volumosas.

### Paralelização de requests

Para cada recurso que uma página possui, um request feito então para carrega-los mais rapidamente precisamos paralelizar essas requisições. O problema é que o HTTP 1.1 é um protocolo sequencial, só podemos fazer 1 request por vez. A solução é abrir mais de uma conexão ao mesmo tempo, paralelizando os requests em 4 a 8 requests (é o limite que temos). Uma forma comum de lidar com isso é usar vários hostnames na página (pag.com e img.pag.com), assim ganhamos mais conexões paralelas.

No HTTP 2 as requisições e respostas são paralelas automaticamente em uma única conexão. É o chamado [multiplexing](http://qnimate.com/what-is-multiplexing-in-http2/).

### Priorização de requests

Uma otimização interessante é a de facilitar a renderização inicial, priorizando os recursos necessários para o usuário ver a página primeiro (CSS) e interagir (JS) depois.

No HTTP 2 podemos indicar nos requests quais deles são mais importantes através de priorização numérica. Assim o browser pode dar prioridade alta a um arquivo CSS no head que bloqueia a renderização, e prioridade mais baixa para um JS assíncrono no fim da página.

### Server Push

Uma gambiarra comum no HTTP 1.1 é fazer inline de recursos, visando a renderização inicial mais rápida. O grande problema aqui é que anulamos o cache do navegador. CSS junto do HTML  não pode ser cacheado independentemente.

Aí vem o Server Push no HTML 2. A ideia é ter o servidor mandando alguns recursos para o navegador sem ele ter requisitado ainda. O servidor "empurra" para o navegador recursos que ele sabe que serão requisitados logo. Assim quando o navegador precisar do recurso, já vai ter em cache e não fará um request.

### Segurança

Um tempo atrás havia uma discussão se HTTP 2 permitiria uso sem SSL (parei de acompanhar faz algum tempo), mas na prática apenas conexões seguras HTTPS serão suportadas. Assim temos segurança e privacidade mais estabelecidas com o protocolo.

Por fim, recomendo o episódio do [Hipsters.tech](http://hipsters.tech/http2-magia-com-o-novo-protocolo/) sobre HTTP2, vai te dar ainda mais informações sobre o assunto

Comment: Gostei da resposta. Tem como explicar um pouco melhor essa parte: "*Aliás, só os headers que mudam são re-enviados, não temos mais aquele excesso de informações mandando todos os headers de novo.*"?

Comment: Claro, vou editar essa parte da resposta para deixá-la mais completa :)

Answer (score 15):

Enquanto o HTTP 1.x é considerado um protocolo textual, o HTTP 2 é considerado **binário**, dificultando a leitura por um humano, mas facilitando para o computador. Isso ocorre porque agora os **pacotes são multiplexados** em uma conexão TCP e são mais compactos, até o **cabeçalho é comprimido**. Ele **aproveita melhor a capacidade do TCP** e **reduz as viagens feitas entre o servidor e o cliente**.

Como consequência, a **latência foi reduzida** e ele está **mais apto a transmitir pacotes maiores e mais rapidamente**, além de **facilitar o [*pipelining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining)** de requisições e respostas, **evitando o [bloqueio do primeiro pacote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-of-line_blocking)** existente no HTTP 1.x.

Algumas características novas foram adicionadas, como:

- a priorização de pacotes e indicação de dependência entre eles;
- informações para gerenciamento de *streams*, pois agora eles possuem um identificador;
- ficou bem mais fácil fazer o [*server push*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2_Server_Push), tão usado hoje em dia, pelo próprio HTTP;
- RESET para cancelar o envio de dados.

Algumas partes do protocolo que eram obrigatórias, mas que nem sempre tinham necessidade, passaram ser opcionais.

Está aberta a possibilidade de se criar extensões ao protocolo conforme a necessidade.

Ele é compatível como o 1.1 e uma negociação decide como comunicar.

Com tudo isso, ele é capaz de atender a demanda de usos variados e não apenas páginas web simples tradicionais que deixou de ser o uso exclusivo do protocolo.

Algumas técnicas que eram usadas para melhorar o desempenho, mas que dificultavam o desenvolvimento não são mais necessárias.

Pode [ler mais detalhes em um livro comunitário](https://http2-explained.haxx.se/content/pt/) do qual me baseei para responder.

> o protocolo já é completamente suportado pelos browsers principais?

O suporte ao protocolo varia. Os [principais navegadores o suportam quase integralmente](http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2). [Servidores também, nas suas versões mais recentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2#Software_and_services_supporting_HTTP.2F2).

[Comparando 1.1 com 2.0](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153512/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

As diferenças [são várias](https://http2-explained.haxx.se/content/pt/), mas vamos começar da mudança mais básica.

O HTTP2 é um **protocolo binário**, diferente do HTTP1 que é em formato texto. Apenas com este conceito já temos muitas diferenças. Com um protocolo binário é mais fácil saber o começo e fim dos pacotes, o que é bem mais complicado de fazer com protocolos textuais. Ou seja, a implementação em si é mais simples.

Com relação as funcionalidades, o HTTP2 veio para resolver problemas e limitações do HTTP1 que os sites atualmente tentam contornar de diferentes maneiras.

Algumas das técnicas usadas com HTTP1 para driblar suas limitações: *Spriting*, *Inlining*, concatenação de arquivos Javascript e *Sharding*.

Não vou entrar nos detalhes de cada uma das técnicas acima, mas o HTTP2 foi implementado para que elas não sejam mais necessárias, corrigindo assim os problemas de latência da primeira versão do protocolo HTTP.

Dentre estas novas funcionalidades do HTTP2, podemos citar:

- **Fluxo multiplexados**: uma mesma conexão pode trazer diferentes tipos de dados (arquivos Javascript, imagens, etc), sendo todos eles misturados sob esta mesma conexão. O destino processará os quadros na ordem em que são recebidos.
- **Prioridades e dependências**: Nos pacotes do fluxo citados anteriormente, alguns deles podem ter prioridade sobre outros. Esta prioridade pode ser alterada dinamicamente. Um exemplo clássico é quando o usuário está visualizando uma página com várias imagens e o usuário decide utilizar a barra de rolagem para carregar as imagens da próxima "página", e neste caso é desejável que estas imagens tenham prioridade sobre as imagens que apareciam na parte de cima da página.
- **Compressão do cabeçalho**: por ser um protocolo stateless (sem estado), o HTTP [repete](https://http2.github.io/faq/#why-do-we-need-header-compression) muitos cabeçalhos a cada requisição e frequentemente eles não mudam a cada requisição. Quando há muita informação repetida, algum tipo de compressão se faz necessária. Atualmente a compressão HTTP na camada TLS (usando `Gzip`) ou mesmo a proposta feita pelo extinto protocolo `SPDY` ajudam neste problema, mas são vulneráveis ao ataque conhecido como [CRIME](https://blog.cloudflare.com/hpack-the-silent-killer-feature-of-http-2/). O HTTP2 suporta um tipo de compressão dedicado aos cabeçalhos, conhecido como `HPACK`, que não apresenta a mesma vulnerabilidade.
- **Reset**: mecanismo para facilitar o fechamento de conexões e começar uma nova. Não é sempre possível fazer isto com o HTTP atual e, quando é, existe um certo custo de rede para isto, pois é preciso negociar uma nova conexão TCP.
- **Server push**: o servidor pode adivinhar que o cliente precisa de um recurso além do que ele inicialmente pediu, já guardando este segundo recurso em cache no cliente, prevendo que ele o solicitará e o receberá (assim) imediatamente.

Creio que estas são as principais mudanças do ponto de vista do usuário "final". Claro que há inúmeras outras diferenças mais técnicas, mas creio que isto responda as principais dúvidas para quem saber o que há de novo e as diferenças.

## O que muda para o desenvolvedor?

De acordo com o [documento criado](https://http2-explained.haxx.se/content/pt/part6.html) por um dos principais contribuidores do protocolo, se fará necessário o uso de ferramentas mais elaboradas para acompanhar as requisições enviadas/recebidas pela página, como o [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org).

Porém, todos os navegadores principais do mercado já suportam o protocolo [desde 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Protocol_support). Assim, as mudanças para o novo protocolo binário são transparentes do ponto de vista do desenvolvedor, que pode acompanhar as requisições que a página envia ou recebe.

Comment: Eu já testei o HTTP2 com o IIS e o chrome e a informacao apareceu da mesma forma que aparece para a versao do protocolo anterior.

Comment: @BrunoCosta, obrigado pelo feedback. Foi exatamente da mesma forma? Fiz uma pesquisa agora aqui e não vi dificuldades no navegador, minha base foi apenas o comentário do autor do protocolo. Vou ajustar esta informação.

Comment: Foi mesmo da mesma forma, é tao igual que a única forma que eu tive como saber (sem recorrer a outras ferramentas) foi habilitar uma coluna que indica qual é o protocolo que está a ser usado para os pedidos. Voce pode ver isso quando navegar no google. Na altura era tudo igual mas parece que alguns cabecalhos sao agora precedidos com ":".

Answer (score 5):

HTTP2 tem suporte para combinar várias queries, compressao de cabeçalhos, prioridades e um sistema de gerenciamento de pacotes mais inteligente. Isso resulta em menor latência e acelera o download do conteúdo em páginas web modernas.

Mais informações aqui: https://bagder.gitbooks.io/http2-explained/content/pt/

Tirei as informações desta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592283/3473971