# No HTTP/2 ainda vou precisar de certificado de segurança ou ele já é encriptado por padrão?

Tags: http, segurança, ssl, http2

<sub>É uma dúvida de leigo, mas gostaria de uma informação sobre o assunto...</sub>

Em HTTP temos a possibilidade de usar um certificado de segurança tipo SSL para garantir a encriptação dos dados que circulam pelo site etc. Dessa forma o protocolo muda para HTTPS.

Eu gostaria de saber se no novo protocolo HTTP/2 eu ainda vou precisar desses certificados, ou se o HTTP/2 já é encriptado por padrão, oferecendo uma conexão mais segura etc. Ou será que vamos ter o protocolo HTTPS2 ou HTTP2S?

No HTTP/2 ainda vou precisar me preocupar com esse tipo de segurança?

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais são as diferenças entre HTTP 2 e HTTP 1.1?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167014/5878)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O fato de ser "encriptado por padrão" não removeria a necessidade de certificados. A encritação e o certificado cumprem um papel completamente diferente.

Além do mais, o HTTP/2 possui o `H2C` (http2 without TLS), que não é encriptado por padrão, mas isso não é suportados pelos navegadores.

---

A encritação apenas tem o intuito de proteger os dados trafegados, isso não é tudo. Apenas ter os dados transferidos de maneira encriptada não é suficiente, já que não há certeza de que está se comunicando com site correto.

O certificado tenta corrigir este problema. O seu dispositivo tem um lista de chaves públicas dos autoridades confiáveis (os "*Certificates Authorities*" ou "*CA*"), então o seu computador confia nessas entidades.

Quando acessa um site (`site.com`) é verificado se o certificado foi emitido por uma dessas autoridades (e também pode ser verificado se o certificado consta no [CT-Log](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/known-logs)), então se o certificado for válido (e foi emitido por um CA que confia) é porque está acessando o site correto. Isso é, ao acessar `site.com` terá certeza de que é o `site.com` que irá receber as informações.

Um agente malicioso, via de regra, não conseguirá forjar um certificado e se passar por `site.com`. Um CA solicitará uma prova para confirmar a titularidade do `site.com` e ele será incapaz de fazer isso. Se fizer, o certificado também constará no CT-Log e será notório que algo errado ocorreu. Se um CA for corrupto ele provavelmente será removido no futuro, como já ocorreu no passado com a Symantec, WoSign, DigiNotar...

*O certificado não confirma se as intenções do site são boas ou ruins. Uma `loja.com` com certificado pode igualmente roubar os seus dados do cartão de crédito. A diferença é que os dados foram enviados de maneira segura e teve certeza de que eles foram destinados para `loja.com`, não foi alguém se passando por `loja.com`, o que poderia ocorrer sem certificado.*

Então os certificados serão ainda necessários, talvez ainda mais, já que precisará deles para usar o HTTP/2.

Comment: E se o agente malicioso utilizar um certificado reconhecido? Ele passaria a ser confiável?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Se o certificado for emitido por uma autoridade que confia, ele é confiável. De alguma maneira ele terá que convencer o CA à emitir um certificado, ou roubar a chave privada do site legitimo. Mas, o que é mais fácil, é  convencer você a confiar numa autoridade não-confiável (enviar um arquivo alá _.crt_ para você e você adicionar ele como confiável) ou se o seu dispositivo já vier de [fabrica com uma autoridade desse naípe](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/02/lenovo-pcs-ship-with-man-in-the-middle-adware-that-breaks-https-connections/).

Comment: Cara agradeço pela resposta, deu para dar uma clareada nas coisas. []´s