# O protocolo HTTP na versão 2 ainda é stateless (sem estado)?

Tags: http, http2

O HTTP é um [protocolo stateless](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119549) (sem estado), ou seja, as requisições e respostas são independentes, assim o servidor não precisa guardar nenhum dado de alguma ação anterior.

Porém com a sua nova versão ([HTTP 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167014)), foi adicionado uma feature:

*"Somente os headers que mudam são re-enviados [...] é possível reaproveitar os headers para as requisições seguintes. Dessa forma, só temos que mandar os cabeçalhos que mudam. Isso reduz as requisições e as deixa menos volumosas."*

Então agora se torna necessário guardar os dados dos cabeçalhos usados anteriormente para enviar apenas os que mudaram. Isso faz com que o HTTP não seja mais sem estado?

Answer (score 4):

Boa tarde, vou dar minha colaboração, apesar de estar estudando o assunto agora.

Da uma olhada na imagem a baixo, pelo que entendi, a ideia é simplesmente reaproveitar o ultimo header, o próprio protocolo vai ficar responsável por reutilizar o ultimo header quando a origem dos dados for a mesma, até que o header seja substituído intencionalmente o expire, não sei se isso é manter estado, porque a conexão não é mantida entre as requisições.

segue uma referencia inicial sobre o assunto: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2/?hl=pt-br

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Primeira analise:**

"se você permitir que nós desfaçamos muitas das soluções paliativas do HTTP/1.1 adotadas antes dentro dos aplicativos e resolvamos esses problemas dentro da própria camada de transporte"

**R:** acredito que o header da própria camada de transporte será responsável por indicar a origem, é o cabeçalho da aplicação que hoje usamos que vai ser reaproveitado, uma das intenções do novo protocolo parece ser a de fazer o que já é feito na camada de aplicação com mais performabce na camada de transporte

**Segunda Analise:**

Olha Stateless na Wiki:

"Em computação, um protocolo sem estado (do inglês stateless) é um protocolo de comunicação que considera cada requisição como uma transação independente que não está relacionada a qualquer requisição anterior, de forma que a comunicação consista de pares de requisição e resposta independentes. Um protocolo sem estado não requer que o servidor retenha informação ou estado de sessão sobre cada parceiro de comunicação para a duração de várias requisições."

**R:** O Servidor continua não tendo responsabilidade em reter essa informação, a camada de transporte estaria responsável pelo reaproveitamento dos cabeçalhos, assim como da compactação e multiplexação, que são os principais ganhos do protocolo.

Comment: E como o HTTP sabe que a origem é a mesma e quais cabeçalhos foram usados anteriormente? O servidor precisa de alguma forma salvar isso, não?

Comment: Editei a resposta com algumas análises despretensiosas, do conteúdo do artigo.

Comment: Não consigo entender ainda. Nos headers é passado a origem da requisição, que considero algo como o IP, então ele compara esse IP com o que? pra saber qual headers retornar?

Comment: O conceito de stateless diz que cada requisição deve ser independente, sem relação com a anterior, o protocolo no entanto que estabelece a conexão que está sendo modificado, se você abrir o console do navegador e verificar a aba Network, no rodapé dela, verá um numero grande de conexões, inclusive com a mesma origem de dados, no novo protocolo as conexões serão mais "duradouras" o que permite um aproveitamento de dados, as requisições da camada de aplicação continuam stateless, porem o protocolo armazena informações sobre os dados que já circularam pela conexão para "reaproveita-los"